# filter image with less damage to edges

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filtering

I have an image like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO6pl.jpg

I want to filter noise with the least possible damage to the edges given this constraint:
The edge is always a straight line with possibility of rotation.
I tried Bilateral Filter. It is pretty good but slow with large scale image.
For now, I am depending on contours filtering to eliminate noise from edges but It would be better if there is a filter that may help before Canny.
Thanks :)

Comment: Try using Gaussian, I find this works most of the time.

Comment: I tried it. It usually kills edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this filter http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/projects/fastwmedian/index.htm

It works like the magic. Very dissimilar images (very low contrast or very high contrast) worked well.
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Kuwahara filter. It was designed to remove image noise and preserve the edge information. It is not available as an OpenCV function, but it's pretty easy to implement and works reasonably fast. [This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuwahara_filter) has everything to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it and give you a feed back if you do not mind.

Comment: I found a ready implementation for Kuwahara filter. However, there is a performance problem.